# replacing NSDictionary with text file

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos

We have a software that is in `objective c`, its running on the mac, but the question is for `iOS` devs as well.

the software is reading many values from `NSDictionary` like this :

```
[self.dic setObject:@"307146" forKey:@"somename-PHOTOGRAPHY"];
```

it than takes the object, and the key before the `-` and after the `-` ,and use it .

We would like to replace the dictionary with `.txt`(or similar)which will be outside the app,  and each row will have a data structure similar to the line here,so we could read it , and have as little changes in code from the current implementation .

Any example of code to create and read lines from a txt would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you probably want is a plist file.

This is an xml file that can be edited using a number of different apps on a Mac. Also text edit (as long as you get the format right).

You can then load the file and it will create an NSDictionary for you that you can use without any code changes.